# Regarding ResponseStatusException returning empty message field in Error Object

Tags: spring-boot, rest, error-handling

I have the following API endpoint in Spring Boot:

```
@GetMapping("/metrics/{id}")
public MetricItem helperMethod(@PathVariable String id) {

        try {
            return customMetricRepository.find(id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException | MetricDoestNotExistException  e) {

            if (e instanceof MetricDoestNotExistException) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(
                        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Metric does not exist", e);
            }
            else {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ErrorCodes.UUID_NOT_FOUND, e);
            }
        }
}
```

When a metric is not found I want to see my "Metric does not exist" in the message field in the error field of the object but I get the below:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-07-01T22:53:44.494+00:00",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "",
   "path": "/api/metrics/e1571021-6a17-4b02-b238-72ac3a1c26cd"
 }
```

Comment: Do you actually have `/api` in your path? For me it is working just fine.

Comment: Yes I do I added it the mapping in app.properties  server.servlet.context-path=/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we just had the same issue.
I found a github discussion where someone pointed out that there was a change within spring-boot 2.3. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22049

If you look into the release notes you can find this section:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content 
There it says: 
**Changes to the Default Error Page’s Content** 
*The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking information to a client. server.error.include-message and server.error.include-binding-errors can be used to control the inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported values are **always**, **on-param**, and **never**.*